# Display & Update in same Django form

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

[A newbie Question] I have a form that shows the student details (query filtered by learner_code). I have an edit button that removes the "disabled" tag from fields & let user edit the form details. I have a Save button as well. I want to save the update back to the same entry in Student model.

My views.py :

```
    query = None
    if 'learner_code' in request.GET:
        query = request.GET['learner_code']
        try:
            student_details = Student.objects.get(learner_code=query)
        except:
            messages.error(request, f'Student Not Found !')
            return redirect('viewstudent')
        else:
            context = { 'student_details' : student_details}
            return render(request, 'students/viewstudent.html', context)
    elif 'learner_code' in request.POST :
        # Save the data back to the table
    else:
        return render(request, 'students/createstudent.html')
```

My model looks like :

```
class Student(models.Model):
    pay = (('FULL', 'FULL'),('EMI', 'EMI'))

    learner_code = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=False, primary_key=True)
    certificate_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=False)
    contact1 = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False)
    contact2 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    batch = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    doj = models.DateField(null=False, default=localtime(now()).date())
    payment_method = models.CharField(choices=pay, max_length=4, default='FULL')
    total_paid = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.learner_code
```

My forms.py is :

```
class StudentCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = '__all__'
```

My Template looks like :

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container mx-auto mt-3">
    {% block form %}
        <form class="form-row mr-auto" action="" method="get">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="learner_code" id="search" placeholder="Learner Code" style="width: 20pc;">
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
    
    {% if messages %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">{{ message }}</div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    <hr>
    <h2>STUDENT DETAILS</h2>
    <div class="row my-2">
        <div class="col-6">
            <label for="id"><h6>LEARNER CODE : </h6></label>
            <input type="text" name="id" id="id" placeholder="{{ student_details.learner_code }}" disabled style="width: 20pc;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <label for="name"><h6>CERTIFICATE NAME : </h6></label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="{{ student_details.certificate_name }}" disabled style="width: 20pc;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row my-2">
        <div class="col-6">
            <label for="contact1"><h6>CONTACT NUMBER : </h6></label>
            <input type="number" name="contact1" id="contact1" placeholder="{{ student_details.contact1 }}" disabled style="width: 20pc;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <label for="contact2"><h6>ALT. CONTACT NO. : </h6></label>
            <input type="number" name="contact2" id="contact2" placeholder="{{ student_details.contact2 }}" disabled style="width: 20pc;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row my-2">
        <div class="col-6">
            <label for="batch"><h6>BATCH : </h6></label>
            <input type="text" name="batch" id="batch" placeholder="{{ student_details.batch }}" disabled style="width: 20pc;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <label for="doj"><h6>DATE OF JOINING : </h6></label>
            <input type="text" name="doj" id="doj" placeholder="{{ student_details.doj }}" disabled style="width: 20pc;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid mx-auto mt-5">
        <button onclick="edits()">Edit</button>
        <form action="" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <h2>FINANCIAL INFORMATION</h2>
    <div class="row my-2">
        <div class="col-6">
            <label for="tenure"><h6>PAYMENT TENURE : </h6></label>
            <input type="text" name="tenure" id="tenure" placeholder="{{ student_details.payment_method }}" disabled style="width: 20pc;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <label for="paid"><h6>TOTAL PAID : </h6></label>
            <input type="number" name="paid" id="paid" placeholder="{{ student_details.total_paid }}" disabled style="width: 20pc;">
        </div>
    </div>
    {% endblock form %}
</div>


<script>
    function edits()
    {
        document.getElementById("id").removeAttribute("disabled")
        document.getElementById("id").setAttribute("value","{{ student_details.learner_code }}")

        document.getElementById("name").removeAttribute("disabled")
        document.getElementById("name").setAttribute("value","{{ student_details.certificate_name }}")

        document.getElementById("contact1").removeAttribute("disabled")
        document.getElementById("contact1").setAttribute("value","{{ student_details.contact1 }}")

        document.getElementById("contact2").removeAttribute("disabled")
        document.getElementById("contact2").setAttribute("value","{{ student_details.contact2 }}")

        document.getElementById("batch").removeAttribute("disabled")
        document.getElementById("batch").setAttribute("value","{{ student_details.batch }}")

        document.getElementById("doj").removeAttribute("disabled")
        document.getElementById("doj").setAttribute("value","{{ student_details.doj }}")
    }
</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use django model form and instance of the query to pre-populate the form to display and update in the same form

```
def your_view(request):
    form = StudentCreationForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        student_details = Student.objects.get(learner_code=query)
        # To pre-populate the form with values using instance
        form = StudentCreationForm(request.POST, instance=student_details) 
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('your_url')
return render(request, "students/createstudent.html", {'form': form })
```